# number of unique products for a selection of orders in sales_flat_order_item

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, sql

Hi fellow programmers,

I'm currently trying to guesstimate how many actions a selection of orders will take to perform. A little context, each unique product ( not a number of products of said product ) counts as an action.

Therefore, if I have 200 orders that need to be processed, the total count of unique products per order should, at a bare minimum, equal that number. However, the following query ( as performed by Magento 1.9.2 ), results in a number lower than 200 ( in my simulations it came close to the actual number of orders, but was still lower ) however, as each order can have multiple products that number should be much higher.

`SQL
SELECT count(main_table.entity_id) AS toship, count(distinct sfoi.item_id) AS products, sfo.shipping_method AS shipment 
FROM sales_flat_shipment AS main_table
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS sfoi ON sfoi.order_id = main_table.order_id
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order AS sfo ON sfo.entity_id = main_table.order_id 
WHERE (shipment_status IS NULL) AND (sfoi.product_type = 'simple') 
GROUP BY sfo.shipping_method`

Obviously, this isn't working as intending, however, my question is, how can I modify this query to reflect the changes I want?

What I think matters is the `count( distinct sfoi.item_id )` which does its aggregation on the whole instead of each unique order, I just don't see how to fix it...

Comment: What will be the output (as per your requirement) if you have 10 orders of a single product?

Comment: if I have 10 orders, each containing a single product, the output would be 10 as well. If I have 10 orders, each containing 2 unique products, the output would be 20. Hope this helps?